# Does the OS make a difference for mining?

Tags: linux, mac, windows

I would like to know whether it makes a difference to mine on Windows, on macOS or on Linux?

1. Performancewise?
2. Is there a big difference in the quantity of software tools available to mine?
3. Are graphics card drivers equally available for all those OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference that you would face is the graphic driver support. 
That kind of influences the performance as well. Windows is best suited that way because of extensive driver support for almost all graphic cards out there.

From mining software perspective, almost all the matured softwares are comptabile on the major platforms you mentioned.

Comment: I can see the lack of drivers on macOS, but what about Linux. I would expect major brands to have Linux drivers for their cards. Is it the case?

Comment: Yes major brands do have their drivers. However when setting up a rig, the major brands cost a lot more than their cheaper counterparts, specifically for which drivers aren't available